# Live() jquery function not working correctly

Tags: jquery, toggle, live

I have this table form:

```
<?php while($resulat = $sql_adherent->fetch_object()): ?>
<tr>
   <td class="highlight">
       <div class="important"></div>
           <a href="#"><?php echo $resulat->nom_compte; ?></a>
   </td>                                 
   <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $resulat->cin; ?></td>
   <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $resulat->sexe; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $resulat->date_naissance; ?></td>
   <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $resulat->date_effet; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $resulat->date_expiration; ?></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="btn default btn-xs red-stripe" id="validate">Validate</a></td>
 </tr>
```

I Want to change "Validate" to "Validated" onclick the id="validate"
and I'm using live() function to do this but it's not working

Here is the code i'm using:

```
$("#validate").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('green-stripe');
    $(this).removeClass('red-stripe');
    $(this).html('Validated');    
  });
```

I tried to change the code to toggle "Validate" & "Validated" using this code,

```
$("#validate").toggle(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  

    $(this).addClass('green-stripe');
    $(this).removeClass('red-stripe');
    $(this).html('Validated');    
  }, function(){
     $(this).addClass('red-stripe');
     $(this).removeClass('green-stripe');
     $(this).html('Validate');
});
```

but also doesn't work.. I know I did something wrong but can"t find the mistake..

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using ? Read https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: did you tried using bind?

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.10.2.min

Comment: Have you recently upgarded jquery? `.live` is deprecated and has been replaced with `.on`

Comment: Nope, I did not try bind()

Comment: I used on.('click', function)

But its only working on the first Row, but not in all the table rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live` is deprecated, so don't try to use it anymore, use `on` instead.

[`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event is deprecated anche can't be used anymore as click handler, in this case you can check if your element have a class as identifying element.

Ref:

> Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed
>   in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named
>   .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the
>   animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments
>   passed.

To switch the classes you can use [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with multiple classes.

Code:

```
$("#validate").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass('red-stripe green-stripe');

    ($(this).hasClass('red-stripe')) ? $(this).html('Validate') : $(this).html('Validated');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/VyD6x/

Answer (score 0):

`.live` is deprecated. Change your js to this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#validate', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$(this).addClass('green-stripe');
$(this).removeClass('red-stripe');
$(this).html('Validated');    
});
```

Comment: I used on.('click', function) But its only working on the first Row, but not in all the table rows

Comment: I'm not writing your validation, just pointing out that `.on` is the proper way to bind to events

Comment: and if I want to use toggle to toggle validate and validated?

Answer (score 0):

Read Live is [Deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) deprecated: 1.8, removed: 1.9

use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Read [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#validate', function(e){
   $(this).toggleClass('green-stripe red-stripe');
});
```